Catch all imports into decorator
Context
I currently have python files like this:
import module1
import module2
from module3 import email_on_error_decorator

@email_on_error_decorator
def main():
   ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()

The decorator email_on_error_decorator sends an email via smtp to notify me there has been an error.
This approach does not work, as if there is an error in the import, it won't be caught.
Question
How can I cleanly send myself an email if there is an error in the imports as well?
Solutions that do not work
I thought of doing that:
from module3 import email_on_error_decorator

@email_on_error_decorator
def main():
   import module1
   import module2
   ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()

but this is ugly, unpythonic, breaks PEP-8, and unfriendly to most IDEs.
I also thought of wrapping the imports into try/except:
try:
   import module1
   import module2
   from module3 import email_on_error_decorator
except:
   send_email()
@email_on_error_decorator
def main():

   ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()

but that feels a little unclean and redundant.
